# No-show menuController and can't figure out how to make the View return True to calling .becomeFirstResponder

Tags: swift

I am having a no-show `menuController` and I have checked all of the suggestions in previous questions. It turns out the `imageView` I have implemented a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on, to show the menu, is returning `False` on calling `.becomeFirstResponder` just before setting up the menu controller.

I am coding in swift 4 and can't figure out how to make the imageView return True to calling `.becomeFirstResponder`. Help!

```
/*********************************************************/
override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

// long tap to show menu that enables deletion of the image.
imageView_1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let longPressRecogniser = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressOnImage(_:)))
//longPressRecogniser.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
//longPressRecogniser.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
longPressRecogniser.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
imageView_1.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecogniser)

imageView_1.image = placeHolderImage_1
imageView_2.image = placeHolderImage_2
}

/*********************************************************/
@IBAction func longPressOnImage(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

print(#function)        
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            //print("gestureRecognizer.state == .began")
            self.tappedView = gestureRecognizer.view!

if tappedView.canResignFirstResponder {
    print("can resign first responder")
}
if tappedView.becomeFirstResponder() {
    print("returned TRUE to becomeFirstResponder")
} else {
    print("returned FALSE to becomeFirstResponder")
}
    // Configure the shared menu controller
    let menuController = UIMenuController.shared

    // Configure the menu item to display
    // Create a "delete" menu item

    let deleteImage = UIMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(deleteImage_1))

    menuController.menuItems = [deleteImage]

    // Set the location of the menu in the view.


    let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: tappedView)
print("location = ", location)
         let menuLocation = CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 2, height: 2)
        menuController.setTargetRect(menuLocation, in: tappedView)

    //update the menu settings to force it to display my custom items
    menuController.update()

    // Show the menu.
    menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
print("menu should be visible now")
        }
    }

/*********************************************************/
@objc func deleteImage_1() {
    print(#function)
}
```

My caveman debugging print statements output:

longPressOnImage

can resign first responder

returned FALSE to becomeFirstResponder

location = (207.0, 82.0)

menu should be visible now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to adri. Your answer is the solution to my problem.
I had read in other posts to similar questions about overriding var canBecomeFirstResponder but either overlooked it or it wasn't made explicit that a custom UIImageView class needs to be created.

Just to make it clear to newbies like me, the class of the imageView in storyBoard and its @IBOutlet in its viewController must typed as ResponsiveImage. If only one of these is changed a type casting error is reported.

Many thanks for ending my hours of frustration! :-)

Comment: Happy to help! If you could mark the answer as correct if you think it is, that would be great. Thanks Ali

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom imageView class and override "canBecomeFirstResponder" property like this:

```
class ResponsiveImage : UIImageView{
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
        return true
    }
}
```

Use this ResponsiveImage type and your code will work :)